# What's going on with the particles in this causative sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, causation

> 余計にテンションが上がる健一に俺は思うわず顔を引き攣らせる。

Why is the one making someone else to do the action (健一) marked with に, marker for the doer of the verb?. If 引き攣る is transitive then maybe it's correct but it's intransitive,  also if that's the case the doer-causer of the action would need to be switched around but In this case it makes more sense in the context for　健一 to be the one causing the action instead. Shouldn't 健一 be marked with が or は instead?

Link to the orginal source of the sentence if anyone need to have a look
https://kakuyomu.jp/works/1177354054889384502/episodes/1177354054889404195

Comment: Typo: 思うわず -> 思わず? I don't think 健一 is the causer but the person the action is directed at. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47611/causative-verbs-in-descriptions-of-people

Comment: What role do you think 顔 plays in that relationship?

Comment: When [intransitive](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-causative-form/#2), the particle を can be used for the doer.